# pathshape not drawing correctly

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-view, android-drawable

if i draw two lines using pathshape in shapedrawble that both have the same starting point, they appear to be drawn at different starting points on the screen. when i draw two lines at the same starting point but at different angles they can in the right circumstances appear to be drawn at different starting points as seen below. This is driving me crazy, any help would be appreciated.

[image: screen shot of two lines that should be at the same starting point]

```
public class drawtest extends View {

private ShapeDrawable  mDrawable;   
Canvas can = null;
float startx;
float starty;
float endx;
float endy;    
float width = 0;
float canvasWidth = 0;
float canvasHeight = 0;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
float height;     
Bitmap bm = null;
Path p;


public drawtest(Context context) {
    super(context);        
    endy=0;
    endx=0;
    startx=0;
    starty=0;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
    mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    canvasHeight = h;
    canvasWidth = w;
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    can = new Canvas(bm);
}


public void test(){
    setStart(canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2);
    double r = 125;
    double tempx = 236;
    double h = startx;
    double k = starty;

    //(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2
    //y = sqrt(r^2 - (x-h)^2) + k        
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        double tempy = Math.sqrt((r*r) - Math.pow((tempx - h),2)) + k;
        setEnd((float) tempx, (float) tempy);
        draw();
        invalidate();
        newCanvas();
        tempx+=56;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();          
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
}


void newCanvas(){
        mDrawable.draw(can);
        can.save();
}

public void setStart(float X, float Y){
    startx = X;
    starty = Y;
}

public void setEnd(float X, float Y){
        endx = X;
        endy = Y;
        width = Math.abs(endx - startx);
        height = Math.abs(endy - starty);
}

private void getnewshape() {
    p = new Path();
    p.moveTo(startx, starty);
    p.lineTo(endx, endy);
    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(p, width, height));

}


public void draw() {
    getnewshape();
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
    mDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                test();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
        }        

    return true;
}   
}
```